# SOLIDITY : [Function Overridding] : -> ParserError: Expected '{' but got reserved keyword 'override'

Tags: blockchain, solidity

I am beginner learning solidity....I m trying function overridding but I am unable to do it and I don't know why it shows error.

```
SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity >=0.4.16 <0.9.0;

contract parent{

    string public str = "Black";
    function check() public view returns(string memory){
        return str;
    }
}

contract child is parent {
    string public st = "Box";
    function check() public view override returns(string memory){  // why this error?...plz help ;-;
        return string(abi.encodePacked(str,st));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pragma solidity >=0.4.16 <0.9.0;` is your problem.

The keywords `virtual` and `override` were added in 0.6.0.

Try

`pragma solidity >=0.6.12 <0.9.0;`

Comment: Oh! well it worked after changes...thanks!